# "Профессор был не()прав"

Tags: орфография

Интересует известная всем толкиенистам-ролевикам сентеция "Профессор был не()прав". Как в данной ситуации пишется "не()прав": слитно или раздельно? С одной стороны, тут подразумевается противопоставление - "профессор не был прав", но с другой - его нет, потому что можно прочитать и как "профессор ошибался". Таким образом, можно написать и так, и этак?
И вот теперь я не знаю, как вернее записать эту фразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения смысла варианты одинаковы, так как в обоих случаях речь идет о несоответствии истине в ее понимании говорящим.

С точки зрения грамматики (интонационной структуры) слитное  написание предпочтительнее, так как раздельная форма хуже читается: профессор был (пауза) не прав.

Если посмотреть в Нацкорпус, то раздельная форма "не прав" встречается чаще, но там другая структура предложений.

Можно предположить, что форма "неправ" категоричнее, чем "не прав", поэтому их использование зависит от ситуации.

Учитывая всё сказанное, будем считать выбор формы написания авторским и отчасти выражающим степень уважения к профессору.